# How is (identical? a b) implemented in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I was just curious, looking around, it seems that Javascript does not have a `equals()` method like Java. Also, neither `==` or `===` can be used to check iff the two operators are the same item. So how is it that Clojurescript has a `==` and a `identical?` operator?

Also, should I expect `identical?` to be substantially faster than `==` in Clojurescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick result from the [Himera ClojureScript REPL](http://himera.herokuapp.com/index.html):

```
    cljs.user> =
    #<function (a, b) {
    return cljs.core._equiv.call(null, a, b)
    }>

    cljs.user> ==
    #<function (a, d, e) {
    switch(arguments.length) {
    case 1:
    return!0;
    case 2:
    return cljs.core._equiv.call(null, a, d);
    default:
    return b.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    throw"Invalid arity: " + arguments.length;
    }>

    cljs.user> identical?
    #<function (a, b) {
    return a === b
    }>
```

According to [Mozilla's JavaScript Reference on Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) the `===` operator *does* compare to see if the two operands are the same object instance, and since `identical?` in clojurescript maps directly onto `===` in JavaScript it will therefore do just that.

The fact that `identical?` maps directly onto `a === b` would also suggest that it'll be significantly faster than `=` or `==` since they both translate to calls to `cljs.core._equiv`. However, it wouldn't surprise me if a good JavaScript JIT engine reduced all three to very similar machine code for numbers since the `-equiv` implementation for numbers just maps onto `identical?`:

```
(extend-type number
  IEquiv
  (-equiv [x o] (identical? x o))
```

Comment: Heh, even after reading your source, I was still confused. "Two objects are never equal for either strictly or abstract comparisons" followed by "An expression comparing Objects is only true if the operands reference the same Object". Maybe I am slow, but it took me a good half minute to figure out how both of those statements could be true. :)

Comment: Yeah, they could have worded that better: "Two _unique object instances_ are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons."

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's just a macro for `===`
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/clj/cljs/core.clj#L208

*Update based on @dnolen's comment*

It's also a function, which just calls `===`:
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L43

Comment: it's also provided as a normal function - the macro is to handle inlineable cases.

Comment: @dnolen Cool, updated my answer to reflect that as well. I'm a little confused by the directory structure of the repo, but I eventually found it...